# Julia: Convert from Vector{Any} to Vector{Symbol}

Tags: julia

I just started coding in Julia due to the open source code of a paper that I want to use.

One remaining error appears within a

```
rename!(data_df, vcat([Symbol("Zbar$i") for i in 1:3],
            [Symbol("ZbarX$i") for i in []],
            [Symbol("X$i") for i in [1]], [:y,:y_pred]))
```

command, in which the following error occurs:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching rename!(::DataFrame, ::Vector{Any})
Closest candidates are:
  rename!(::AbstractDataFrame) at C:\Users\###\.julia\packages\DataFrames\Lrd7K\src\abstractdataframe\abstractdataframe.jl:248
  rename!(::AbstractDataFrame, ::AbstractVector{Symbol}; makeunique) at C:\Users\###\.julia\packages\DataFrames\Lrd7K\src\abstractdataframe\abstractdataframe.jl:199
  rename!(::AbstractDataFrame, ::AbstractVector{<:AbstractString}; makeunique) at C:\Users\###\.julia\packages\DataFrames\Lrd7K\src\abstractdataframe\abstractdataframe.jl:207
```

.

I fixed the error by manually inserting the output of the previously shown `vcat()` command:

`rename!(data_df_test,[:Zbar1,:Zbar2, :Zbar3, :X1, :y, :y_pred] )`.

When comparing the datatype of the initial and manually inserted rename-vectors, I observe 2 different vector types: Vector{Any} (fails) and Vector{Symbol} (works).

#1

```
vcat([Symbol("Zbar$i") for i in 1:3],
                   [Symbol("ZbarX$i") for i in []],
                   [Symbol("X$i") for i in [1]], [:y,:y_pred])
6-element Vector{Any}:
 :Zbar1
 :Zbar2
 :Zbar3
 :X1
 :y
 :y_pred
```

#2

```
[:Zbar1,:Zbar2, :Zbar3, :X1, :y, :y_pred]
6-element Vector{Symbol}:
 :Zbar1
 :Zbar2
 :Zbar3
 :X1
 :y
 :y_pred
```

My question: How can I change the `vcat()` vector from a Vector{Any} to a Vector{Symbol}?

Comment: Both your examples return `Vector{Symbol}` for me on v1.8. What Julia version are you using?

Comment: BTW, you can simplify your expression with broadcasting: `Symbol.("Zbar", 1:3)`, for example.

Comment: I actually also use v1.8.2 on windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was commented under your question in this case on Julia 1.8 there is no issue. However, there would be issue in the following case:

```
julia> vcat([Symbol("Zbar$i") for i in 1:3], [])
3-element Vector{Any}:
 :Zbar1
 :Zbar2
 :Zbar3
```

which is resolved by changing the syntax to:

```
julia> Symbol[[Symbol("Zbar$i") for i in 1:3];
              []]
3-element Vector{Symbol}:
 :Zbar1
 :Zbar2
 :Zbar3
```

The point is that `vcat` does not allow passing type-hint for target collection while by using the vector-style syntax it is possible.

The reason why we cannot reproduce the problem in your case is that under Julia 1.8:

```
julia> [Symbol("ZbarX$i") for i in []]
Symbol[]
```

(note that the same behavior is under Julia 1.0.5 so if there is a problem it must be under a very old Julia)

Comment: Thank you! Replacing vcat(...) with Symbol[...] fixed my problem. However, opposing your intuition I also use the current julia version v.1.8.2 on Windows 10 and also updated all packages using Pkg.update().
You were correct, problematic term forcing vector{any} was "Symbol("ZbarX$i") for i in []".